# How to reduce size of the vertical panel icons in xfce4?

Tags: xfce, xfce-panel

Here's my vertical panel:

How do I reduce the size of the whisker and battery icons (while keeping the same panel width)?

[image: 1]

Comment: nobody? just downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it turns out you can do this by increasing the number of rows while reducing the row size.

[image]